# Default Reference Type of anonymous object in Java

Tags: java, oop, reference

Suppose my code is,

```
class A {
    void print() {
        System.out.println('A');
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void print() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C {
    void print(A a) {
        System.out.println("AA");
    }
    void print(B b) {
        System.out.println("BB");
    }
}

class test {
    C c = new C();
    c.print(new B());    // line 3
}
```

And when I run this code, line 3 prints "BB". If I delete my method `void print(B b)` in class C, then line 3 prints "AA". I know polymorphism, inheritance and pass-by-value concepts. My question is why reference type of `new B()` is of type `B` and is of type `A` when I delete the method in class C. Is it some kind of official rule that I missed? What happens at compilation phase and runtime phase?

Comment: Hint: `new B()` is not an anonymous object, is an object of type `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`B` is a child of `A` . So `B` can be used in place of `A`.

So when you remove the method with type `B b`. It chooses the method with `A a` directly with no confusion.

Confusion occurs when there are multiple methods that are accessible with same rules (overloading). In that case **most specific method will be chosen**. In absence of method with `B a`, `A a` will be chosen and when there `B b` that will be chosen because `B` is most specific than `A` for the method with type `B a`.

So in the chain of choosing specific, `Child` have the greatest priority and `Parent` have least.

```
B > A > ... > .. >Object
```

[15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

Comment: Since this is method overloading, "most specific method choosing" happens at compile time phase, right?